# Problem with packages siunitx, datatool and xkeyval

Tags: siunitx, datatool, xkeyval

After having read several articles concerning the `siunitx` problem I am still struggling with my problem. Your comments and your help is highly appreciated.

The following error occurs when I switch on the datatool package:

```
xkeyval: `footstyle' undefined in families `beamerthemeFrederiksberg'. \ProcessOptionsBeamer
```

I manually installed the following packages: `siunitx.tds`, `l3packages.tds` and `l3kernel.tds`.

Minimum example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%******** PACKAGES ***********************************
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}               
\usepackage[english]{babel}             
\usepackage{hyperref}                   
\usepackage{url}                    
\usepackage{graphicx}                   
\usepackage{epstopdf}               
\usepackage{color}                  
\usepackage{enumerate}                  
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{booktabs}               
\usepackage{cite}                   
\usepackage[square,sort]{natbib}    
\usepackage{filecontents}

%******** COLORS *************************************
\definecolor{FSBlueMain}        {RGB}{55,67,123}
\definecolor{EngagementBlueA}   {RGB}{140,184,198}
\definecolor{EngagementBlueB}   {RGB}{92,127,146}
\definecolor{EngagementBlueC}   {RGB}{75,146,219}
\definecolor{EngagementBlueD}   {RGB}{33,49,77}
\definecolor{EngagementYellowA} {RGB}{254,209,0}
\definecolor{EngagementYellowB} {RGB}{198,172,0}
\definecolor{EngagementGreen}   {RGB}{64,74,41}
\definecolor{CorporateGreen}    {RGB}{182,191,0}
\definecolor{ExcellenceOrangeA} {RGB}{224,82,6}
\definecolor{ExcellenceOrangeB} {RGB}{225,160,47}
\definecolor{CorporateMarron}   {RGB}{145,120,91}
\definecolor{InnovationCoolGray}{RGB}{97,99,101}

\colorlet{BgTransition}{InnovationCoolGray}


%*****************************************************
%******** FREDERIKSBERG THEME ************************
%*****************************************************

\usetheme[not@ku={University XYZ},
    footstyle=low,                  
    wide,                           
    TPomitframeno,              
    FTalign=left,                   
    greyfoot,                       
    seriftitles,                    
    fnolabel=Slide,                 
    basecolour=FSBlueMain,  
    topbarcolour=FSBlueMain         
    ]{Frederiksberg}

%******** SET BEAMER CLASS COLORS ********************
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=CorporateGreen}
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{bg=ExcellenceOrangeA}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=ExcellenceOrangeA}

%******** REMOVE HEADERS AND FOOTER IN HANDOUT MODE **
\mode<handout>{
  \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]{}
}

%******** PDF SETUP **********************************
\hypersetup{
    pagebackref,                        
    pdfnonfullscreenpagemode=UseThumbs, 
    colorlinks=false
}

%******** META PRESENTATION INFORMATION **************
\title
    [Title] % Short Title
    {\large{Title}} % Long Title
\author{Your name}                                          
\institute{Your institute}
\date{\today}

%******** CHANGE BACKGROUND COLOR ********************
\newcommand{\SlideTransition}[2][]{
  \mode<all> {
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=BgTransition}
  }

  \begin{frame}<handout:0>[plain]
  \vspace{3.5cm}
  \begin{flushright}
    {\Huge \rmfamily \slshape \textcolor{white}{#2}} \linebreak
    #1
    \end{flushright}
  \end{frame}

  \mode<all> {
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
  }
}


%*****************************************************
%******** ESTOUT PACKAGE *****************************
%*****************************************************

\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{#1}}

\let\estinput=\input

\newcommand{\estwide}[3]{
        \vspace{.75ex}{
            \begin{tabular*}
            {\textwidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{#2}{#3}}
            \toprule
            \estinput{#1}
            \bottomrule
            \addlinespace[.75ex]
            \end{tabular*}
            }
        }   

\newcommand{\estauto}[3]{
        \vspace{.75ex}{
            \begin{tabular}{l*{#2}{#3}}
            \toprule
            \estinput{#1}
            \bottomrule
            \addlinespace[.75ex]
            \end{tabular}
            }
        }

    \newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

%********** CUSTOM TABLE SUBCAPTIONS *****************
\newcommand{\figtext}[1]{
    \vspace{-1.9ex}
    \captionsetup{justification=justified, font=footnotesize}
    \caption*{\hspace{6pt}\hangindent=1.5em #1}
    }
\newcommand{\fignote}[1]{\figtext{\emph{Note:~}~#1}}
\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{\figtext{\emph{Source:~}~#1}}
\newcommand{\starnote}{\figtext{* p < 0.1, ** p < 0.05, *** p < 0.01. Standard errors in parentheses.}}

%********** SETUP SIUNITX PACKAGE ********************
    \sisetup{
        per = fraction,
        parse-numbers = false,
        detect-mode,
        tight-spacing       = true,
        group-digits        = false ,
        input-signs     = ,
        input-symbols       = ( ) [ ] - + *,
        input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        table-align-text-post   = false
        }

%*****************************************************
%********** BEGIN DOCUMENT ***************************
%*****************************************************

\begin{document}
\mode* 

%******** TITLE PAGE *********************************
\begin{frame}
    \vspace{1.6cm}
    %\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{Frankfurt.png}
    \titlepage


\end{frame}
%*****************************************************
\end{document}
```

I did not post the log file due to character limitations.

Comment: The `Frederiksberg` theme is non-standard: can you let us know where you obtained it from?

Comment: Dear Joseph, of course. I used the Frederiksberg-2-2.zip file in the download section at:
(http://www.matdat.life.ku.dk/LaTeX/Frederiksberg/)

Comment: Why are you installing standard packages manually?

Comment: Does the problem still manifest with an up-to-date TeX distribution? The theme link is dead so can't test but with a standard theme I only get errors due to outdated `siunitx` instructions.